# How to show a div only on mouse hover and hide when mouse leaves

Tags: jquery

I have a menu and I am trying to show it only when an image icon is hovered using jquery Please help me. I have used the following code but it doesn't work. It makes it appear but don't disappear it when mouse leaves.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hover").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(".overlay").show();
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(".overlay").hide();
    });
});
```

Here is Html

```
<----div which is to be hovered---->
<div class="box"><img alt="101helper-menu" class="hover" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-JzmiWYq3mb4/VYHPosbeBcI/AAAAAAAACuI/J0EQbhp2oKY/s1600/menu-icon-101helper.png">
```

**<----div which is to be shown on hover and disappear on mouse leave---->**

```
<div class="overlay">
<div id="cssmenu"><ul><li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Blogger%20Tips%20And%20Tricks">Blogger Tips and tricks</a></li>
<li class="active has-sub"><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Blogger%20Seo%28Search%20Engine%20Optimization">Seo</a><ul>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Blogger%20Seo%28Search%20Engine%20Optimization">Blogger Seo</a></li>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Google%20Webmaster%20Tools%20tutorials">Google Webmaster Tools</a></li></ul></li>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Blogger%20menus">Menus for blogger</a></li>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Blogger%20Widgets%20And%20Gadgets">Blogger widgets and gadgets</a></li>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Beginner%20to%20blogging">Beginner to blogging</a></li>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Mobile%20Blogging">Mobile blogging</a></li>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/p/about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/p/hire-us.html">Hire us</a></li>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/p/contact-me.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/p/menusitemap.html">Sitemap</a></li></ul></div></div></div>
```

Comment: FYI, you can do this with pure CSS

Comment: Yes but I want to do it with jquery or javascript

Comment: @Pranav C Balan I have added html

Comment: I have put your code on jsfiddle and it works quite well... the only thing i did was hiding the overlay on load https://jsfiddle.net/4dyvpq7v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have registered the `hover` on the image that has the class `hover` and NOT on the div `overlay` itlself. So only when your mouse *leaves* that image will that div get hidden.

Try doing as in the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hover").on("mouseenter", function() {
       $(".overlay").show();
    });
    $(".overlay").on("mouseleave", function() {
       $(this).hide();  //or $('.overlay').hide()
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/x7Lww0pv/1/)

***Issue with your page detected!***

I tried running my own jQuery code on your page and you know what I found?
Your page has *many* versions of jQuery being loaded and somehow, some older version of jQuery overrides the newer version.

How do I know this?
   Running jQuery's `.on()` method resulted in type errors. As per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), the `on()` method is added in version 1.7.

**Solution:** Since I cannot make YOUR page load only the latest jQuery, I tried the above code in an *older* style, so the following worked:

```
$(function() {
   $(".hover").mouseenter(function() {
      $(".overlay").show();
   });
   $(".overlay").mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).hide();  //or $('.overlay').hide()
   });
});
```

Comment: Yes I know but its not working in my blog you can check it here http://101helper.blogspot.com/

Comment: @FahimRaza try my updated answer. Meanwhile, for an even better result, you can replace `.hover` with it's immediate parent i.e. `.box`.

Comment: Thanks bro but @Nageshwar Reddy helped me out and its working properly

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#cssmenu").hide();

$(".hover").mouseover(function () {
    $("#cssmenu").slideDown('slow');
});
$(".overlay").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#cssmenu").slideUp('slow');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1bg3hbr5/4/)

Comment: I have tried this code, it works to show it only but I want it to show when the user hover over the menu and disappear which the user leaves the menu

Comment: Your code is working fine but it should disappear when mouse leaves

Comment: copy the code n execute in console, working fine for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88307/discussion-between-nageshwar-reddy-and-fahim-raza).

Comment: Did you check on my blog? I have used the updated code still not working by the way thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call `$(".overlay").hide();` before `$(".hover").on()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".overlay").hide();
    $(".hover").on({
      "mouseenter": function() {
        $(".overlay").show();
      }
      , "mouseleave": function() {
        $(".overlay").hide();
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <img alt="101helper-menu" class="hover" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-JzmiWYq3mb4/VYHPosbeBcI/AAAAAAAACuI/J0EQbhp2oKY/s1600/menu-icon-101helper.png">
</div>
<div class="overlay">
  <div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Blogger%20Tips%20And%20Tricks">Blogger Tips and tricks</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active has-sub"><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Blogger%20Seo%28Search%20Engine%20Optimization">Seo</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Blogger%20Seo%28Search%20Engine%20Optimization">Blogger Seo</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Google%20Webmaster%20Tools%20tutorials">Google Webmaster Tools</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Blogger%20menus">Menus for blogger</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Blogger%20Widgets%20And%20Gadgets">Blogger widgets and gadgets</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Beginner%20to%20blogging">Beginner to blogging</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/search/label/Mobile%20Blogging">Mobile blogging</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/p/about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/p/hire-us.html">Hire us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/p/contact-me.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://101helper.blogspot.com/p/menusitemap.html">Sitemap</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```